Trouble Using Arduino IDE for BARTH STG-850: How To Get The IDE To Connect To The Board
I am trying to use a BARTH STG-850 connected with an ST-LINK V2, with Arduino as the IDE, but when I try to compile any code, I get the following error:
fatal error: variant.h: No such file or directory
The IDE also does not seem to be able to find the BARTH board when it is connected and powered, although the computer can tell there is something in the port and the light on the ST-Link is on.
I tried following the instructions on two different computers (one Ubuntu the other Windows), but I don't think the error is related to how the software is downloaded.
I was previously having a problem where the stm32f0xx_hal_conf.h file was missing, but I just copy pasted it into the directory, and now it says it is missing "variant.h"
I'm currently just trying to get it to connect and get Blink to run.

The guy who developed the STG-850 Arduino Core decided to zipped the board files in a compressed file, you need to go into the Boards folder of your installation and unzip the file.

The error message you are seeing: fatal error: variant.h: No such file or directory is related to the Arduino core for the BARTH STG-850ST-LINKV2.
This error message indicates that the variant.h file, which is part of the core, cannot be found.
This can be caused by a variety of issues, such as an incorrect installation of the core or a problem with the board's configuration.
See answer in this article:
source: troubleshooting stg850
